# PHP Cookie Issue

Tags: php, forms, cookies

I am trying to create a html form that will get username, name, and email address and php will store the username as a cookie. Then, store username, name, and email address.

Then, when they log go to form again, the form will greet the user with cookie information. I am unsure how to proceed, if anyone can give me suggestions. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <form action = "userinfo.php" method = "post">

        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>

        Fullname:<br>
        <input type="text" name="fullname">

        <br> Email:<br>
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>



<?php

session_start();

$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "username";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day


if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}

?>
```

Comment: What problems/errors do you have?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: You can't use `session_start()` after all that output. You have to have that function BEFORE any output is sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP superglobal ($_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER, $_COOKIE, etc...) are set **ONCE** when the script first starts up, and then are never changed again by PHP.

Whatever cookies you create with `setcookie()` will only appear in $_COOKIE on the **NEXT** script execution.

The sole exception to this is `$_SESSION`, which gets populated after `session_start()` is called.